# Access Week format destroyed on Excel Export

Tags: excel, ms-access, export-to-excel, date-formatting

I have an access database and there is a date column formatted as "FW"ww  -  yyyy this results in showing a date like "FW23 - 2015" but holds still the value of the date. "ww" stands for fiscal week.

This date is also in an query which gets exported to Excel often. The problem is that Excel does not know the "ww" format option resulting in FWww - 2015.

When turning off the apply format option on exporting the date will not be formatted and shown like "10.07.2015" which is not the desired result.

There is a workaround: just run the query copy all rows and on pasting in excel chose "Match Destination Formatting" and delete the added row on the top.

Is there a more automatic way to reach that result?

Comment: have your tried converting it as an ordinary string in your export query? The value should then get passed as a string to excel and keep it's format. Excel won't recognize it as a date, but as long as you're not using it for calculations in excel and just using it for viewing, you should be ok.

Comment: The inner format wont change the value, so the outer format will access the same date value (not the "FW23 - 2015") and will make a 10.07.2015 again.